# Why are images are not load by a compiled nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, angular, babeljs, mean-stack, packaging

After creating an application using the **MEAN** stack, I am trying to compile it using the **pkg** package https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg.

The application works fine, the HTML and CSS files are rendered, the connection with the database and my APIs are working correctly but images cannot be loaded.

*NB:* images are in the same folder as HTML and CSS files.

First of all, here is how my app is structured:

```
my-app
    |__ app-server
    |            |__ index.js
    |            |__ package.json
    |            |__ lib
    |            |__ all the other files and directories
    |
    |__ app-client
                 |__dist
                 |     |__app
                 |           |__ index.html
                 |           |__ style.css
                 |           |__ assets/images
                 |           |__ othermain.js files
                 |
                 |__ all the other files and directories
```

Second, here is how my application work:

- My Angular application is built using ng build into the **app-client/dist/app** directory and it is rendered from my Nodejs server.
- All the images SRC and HREF in my angular application are set to paths like this:

```
src="assets/images/my-image.svg"
```

- From the **index.js** file in the Node.js server I am serving static files (images, CSS, HTML files) from the built angular app using this snippet of code:

```
// enable static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../app-client/dist/app')));
```

- And rendering my HTML file like this:

```
// routes
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{ 
    res.sendFile(path.join(process.env.BASE_PATH, '../app-client/dist/app/index.html'));
});
```

- I transpiled my Nodejs server using **babel** into the **lib** folder
- I packaged my app using **pkg** with this configuration from the **package.json** file:

```
{
  // other configs

 "bin": {
    "app": "index.js"
  },
  "pkg": {
    "scripts": [
      "lib/**/*.js"
    ],
    "assets": [
      "other assets",
      "../app-client/dist/app/*"
    ]
  }

  // other configs
}
```

*NB:* the application works perfectly locally using the angular as a built application.

Can anyone help me please, to find the problem and correct it?